# trying to rotate a globe in d3, centering on a particular country

Tags: d3.js

There is probably a simple answer to this question... . I'm using d3 to create a globe, showing all countries. I also have a div with the name of all the countries in it. When I click on a country name, I want the globe to spin to that country. But I'm having trouble getting the syntax right. Can anyone help, please?

```
var feature;

    var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
        .scale(zoom)
        .origin([-71.03,42.37])
        .mode("orthographic")
        .translate([380, 450]);

    var circle = d3.geo.greatCircle()
        .origin(projection.origin());

    var scale = {
      orthographic: 380,
      stereographic: 380,
      gnomonic: 380,
      equidistant: 380 / Math.PI * 2,
      equalarea: 380 / Math.SQRT2
    };

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);


    var svg = d3.select("#globe").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 800)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .on("mousedown", mousedown);

    var g = svg.append("g");

    d3.json("simplified.geojson", function(collection) {

        g.append("g")
          .attr("id", "countries")
        g.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
          .data(collection.features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", clip)
          .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.ISO3; })
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.properties.FILL; }) //change color and make clickable if data on this country exists
          .on("mouseover", pathOver)
          .on("mouseout", pathOut)
          .on( "dblclick", dblclick)
          .on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
          .on("click", click);

        feature = svg.selectAll("path");

        feature.append("svg:title")
          .text(function(d) { return d.properties.NAME; });

//here is where I want to be able to click a country name in the div and have the globe rotate to that country:

        $('.represented').click(function(){
                var countryabbrev = $(this).attr('id'); 
                projection.origin(projection.invert(#path.centroid(#CAN))); //this line is wrong
                refresh(1500);
                showPerson(countryabbrev)
            });
```

Comment: Well, I've gotten it to find the center and rotate, but the rotation is really hinky:

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten it to find the country and rotate. Now the rotate is sketchy, but at least there's progress:

```
$('.represented').click(function(){
                var countryabbrev = $(this).attr('id'); 
                getCentroid(d3.select("#" + countryabbrev));
                //projection.origin(projection.invert(#path.centroid(#CAN)));
                projection.origin(getCentroid(d3.select("#" + countryabbrev)));
                refresh(1500);
                //showPerson(countryabbrev)
            });

        function getCentroid(selection) {
            // get the DOM element from a D3 selection
            // you could also use "this" inside .each()
            var element = selection.node(),
                // use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box
                bbox = element.getBBox();
            // return the center of the bounding box
            return [bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2];
        }
```